# Error in rep.int(sep, ncolumns - 1) : invalid 'times' value in bayesx function [R2BayesX package] in R

Tags: r, error, spatial-statistics, spatio-temporal-data, code-review

I am trying to run a STAR model within the R2BayesX package using the bayesx function. My model works with the cases of leptospirosis in Colombia ('observed' and 'expected') by department in a quarterly assessment between the year 2007 and 2018.  In this model, I have entered a covaraible called 'humidity' that contains the relative humidity in each department by quarter. The temporal data I have set it with the first day of each quarter (2007-01-01 , 2007-04-01, ...) but inside the STFDF object I have numbered them from 1 to 48 inside the column 'num_trim', finally the ID of the departments I have identified them according to ID. the code I execute is the following:

```
bayesx_leptos_hum <- R2BayesX::bayesx(
  formula = observados~humedad + sx(num_trim, bs = "rw1") + sx(ID , bs = "spatial" , map = graf_leptos),
  offset = log(leptos$esperados),
  family = "poisson" ,
  data = as(
    object = leptos,
    Class = "data.frame"
  )
)
```

When running the code I get the following error:

```
 > Error in rep.int(sep, ncolumns - 1) : invalid 'times' value.
```

This is the structure of the head of the dataframe:

```
structure(
   list(
      trimestre = structure(c(1167609600, 1167609600, 1167609600, 1167609600, 1167609600, 1167609600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
      ID_ESPACIA = c(5L, 8L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 17L),
      num_trim = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
      observados = c(0, 21, 0, 2, 0, 2), 
      esperados = c(26.54863575, 10.12593855, 32.0785374, 8.72391975, 5.73673555, 4.42528905),
      humedad = c(84.8966666666667, 79.3733333333333, 76.1466666666667, 79.0433333333333, 84.1266666666667, 78.75), 
      precipitacion = c(54.49, 49.22, 0, 58.0066666666667, 65.04, 49.22), 
      temperatura = c(16.68, 16.1433333333333, 27.4933333333333, 13.7266666666667, 16.4266666666667, 24), 
      ID = 1:6), 
   row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame"
)
```

Comment: can you share a `dput(head(yourdataframe))` so we can explore the variables?

Comment: Is your R code incomplete? It looks like the name of the function being called and maybe some arguments aren't at the top.

Comment: @ElioDiaz This returns r  ``` structure(list(trimestre = structure(c(1167609600, 1167609600, 
1167609600, 1167609600, 1167609600, 1167609600), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), ID_ESPACIA = c(5L, 8L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 
17L), num_trim = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), [first part]

Comment: @ElioDiaz [second part] observados = c(0, 
21, 0, 2, 0, 2), esperados = c(26.54863575, 10.12593855, 32.0785374, 
8.72391975, 5.73673555, 4.42528905), humedad = c(84.8966666666667, 
79.3733333333333, 76.1466666666667, 79.0433333333333, 84.1266666666667, 
78.75), precipitacion = c(54.49, 49.22, 0, 58.0066666666667, 
65.04, 49.22), temperatura = c(16.68, 16.1433333333333, 27.4933333333333, 
13.7266666666667, 16.4266666666667, 24), ID = 1:6), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")  ```

Comment: @Spacedman Yes, due to an error, the first command line was not visible.

Comment: I've edited the info in your comment into the question, and formatted it so we can easily see what the columns are all like. Without information about your data its always very hard to work out why someone is getting error messages!